# Retrieve a user_id from a specific guard

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.3

I have three accounts in my application, this definitely means I have three guards. In my controller when I do this :

```
 dd($apartment->user_id = Auth::id());
```

I get the users user_id from the users table. I would like to get the user_id from the agents table whose guard I have named agent. I try this :

```
dd($apartment->user_id = Auth::agent()->id);
```

and I get this error :

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::agent().

Does anyone know how I can correctly point to my desired guard?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get user_id of a specific guard : `Auth::guard('name_of_your_guard')->id();`